# print value from first line on each line

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have file of following format:

```
 1.0
 2.0
 3.0
 4.0
 5.0
```

Is it possible to copy value in first line `1.0` to the beginning of every line in awk? Like this:

```
 1.0 1.0
 1.0 2.0
 1.0 3.0
 1.0 4.0
 1.0 5.0
```

Comment: With GNU sed: `sed -n '1{h;G;s/\n/ /p}; :j;g;N;s/\n/ /p;bj' file` In this case, `awk` is more transparent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
awk 'NR==1 {f=$1} {print f,$1}' file
```

Output:

```
1.0 1.0
1.0 2.0
1.0 3.0
1.0 4.0
1.0 5.0
```

If current line number (`NR`) is 1 then save column 1 (`$1`) to variable `f`. For every line print content of variable `f` and content of column 1.

Comment: i though like you ! lol but he want different thing. :D i edited my answer to achieve his target.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this by sed command working as expected

---

```
k=`sed -n 1p file`;sed "s/^/$k /g" file
```

---

output

---

```
1.0 1.0
1.0 2.0
1.0 3.0
1.0 4.0
1.0 5.0
```

---